# Getting null from GetHostEvidence()

Tags: c#

I'm trying to follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx to create a sandbox to run untrusted code.

When I execute this in my Sandboxer class:

```
StrongName fullTrustAssembly = typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
```

I will get null returned. Why? How do I fix it?

Comment: This code does not compile on my machine.  .Net 4.0, VS2010.  According to MSDN, it requires a type parameter of the specific type of evidence you want.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414187.aspx

Comment: The code in the question looked incorrect because the StrongName part was cut out when I used <pre> to surround the code block. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the page you linked, all of the calls to `GetHostEvidence<T>()` are being supplied with `StrongName` as the type parameter.  If the assembly doesn't have a strong name (not all do), it will return null.

Comment: Why wouldn't it have a StrongName? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You must sign your application. The easiest way to do it is:

1. Right click on your **project** in the Solution Explorer and select **Properties**
2. Go to **Signing** tab
3. Check **Sign the assembly**
4. From drop box, select **<New...>**
5. Type a name in **Key file name**
6. Password is optional, so you can uncheck **Protect my key file with a password**
7. Click **Ok**

Run the **Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox** sample again. It should work.